# exception log in Android Market Place

Tags: android

I'm seeing this exception in my android Market Developer Console -->Crash errors

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:398)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:366)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1943)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1143)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1756)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656)
at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1314)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1587)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1794)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9330)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3795)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9330)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3795)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1201)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1944)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the things which i don't understand about this error:

1. Where is it coming from (i don't see any reference to my classes in this trace)?
2. Does it mean the application shuts down because of this errors?
3. What is the mechanism by which this error gets logged in market place?

Note : there are no user messages in the error log.

Comment: That's a tough one to debug.  I'd start by looking at any `ArrayAdapter` items you may have in your application.  Check to see if they can be null and try to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either it expects a TextView in your layout which is not there, or an item in your list is null. The relevant source is at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cint%29, line 398 corresponds to line 355 on this page.